# In Kafka, only one producer calls the send() method, but all producers start sending messages, why?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, message-queue

In Kafka, different producers are configured with different bootstrap servers, and only one producer calls the send() method, but all producers start sending messages.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQXsp.png)

messageQueueList.getQueueList() contain some producers.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqPqK.png)
Only the producer m called the send() method, but every producer tried to send message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWv0t.png)

In my design,  MessageQueue m = messageQueueList.getQueueList().get(index); different index can use different producer to send message, but all the producers send messages no mattter what the index is.

Comment: 1) Please show your code as a [mcve], not as images 2) Unclear where clientId 2 even comes from